# Can we use a JVM variable to hold the status of a job dynamically

Tags: java

I have a Spring batch job running 4 times a day.Once the job is started, it checks the status of the previous job. If previous job status is "started", then the job is aborted. I have a query to check that. The problem is that, if one job fails checking the previous job status, its status will be "failed" and the next job will start processing, so that two instances will run in parallel. So we have to manually stop one.This forces us to consistently monitor the job. So, I have also tried by changing the query to check for previous 5 job runs. That is fine. But is there any other way using JVM or some other techniques that we can meet this criteria??

Please suggest..!

Comment: Perhaps some simple locking mechanism?

Comment: I am not sure if you can use the Quartz scheduler with spring batch... if you can, Quartz has StatefulJobs which prevents multiple instances of the job running concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought, but would it make sense to use a timestamp as status?

The other possibility would be to make your

> if one job fails checking the previous job status, its status will be "failed"

checking more robust. Where is the gap that makes it possibly fail? Probably you want to use some locking mechanism (file locks, db locks, mutexes).

Answer (score 0):

If no 2 jobs can run at the same time, it is probably because there is a resource that you want to protect. Locking mechanisms are best suited for this. Read [Java Concurrency In Practice](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601) for more info on that. If you don't have quick access to this excellent book, you can start at http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Answer (score 0):

One option would be using [FileLock](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileLock.html) to control to prevent more than one instance of your app/jvm to operate the same time.

Use some file to represent status of the "job". Try to acquire lock on this file once job started. Write status of the job to this file and release lock once done. If job failed to acquire the lock on file - there is another job running - do whatever is relevant in your case (fail silently, or kill previous job, for example).

This is a common approach for solving problems like this in UNIX world.

**UPDATE:** [here](http://www.javabeat.net/2007/10/locking-files-using-java/) is a simple example showing how to work with FileLock.